# How to make Fragment modal like ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

We have a simple fragment with progress bar

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Is it possible to make this fragment being modal? (i.e. ignoring any clicks behind progress bar and back button press)
I suppose not to write any code in FragmentActivity, cause activity hosts too many other fragments besides that temporary one, and it's logically better not to manipulate them from activity.

I tried to search over deprecated ProgressDialog, found an idea of setting window flags, but it hasn't denied pressing back.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

P.S. For some reasons we can't use DialogFragment with *setCancellable(false)*, they're automatically dismissing on screen rotations

Comment: DialogFragments *are* saved and restored over rotations. You should look at why that isn't the case for you.

Comment: ianhanniballake, finally, it seems no other easy alternatives to DialogFragment. I used that without(!) setRetainInstance(true) and all working well. But, it's still interesting from hacking point, how to create a modal fragment

Comment: Yes, retained Fragments should absolutely not be used with anything with a UI, DialogFragments included.